# XamDataGrid arrow key navigation not working

Tags: c#, xaml, infragistics

I have a very simple XamDataGrid with test data that doesn't want to navigate with the arrow keys.

XAML:

```
<dataPresenter:XamDataGrid x:Name="testGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" DataSource="{Binding Tests}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> tests = new ObservableCollection<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

public ObservableCollection<string> Tests
{
    get => tests;
    set
    {
        tests = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Tests));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean when you press the <Up> and <Down> keys the selected line still the same?

Comment: @Jackdaw yes, exactly

Comment: The code above is working for me without a problem. Perhaps you have another controls that can impact the required functionality? What version of the Infragistics are you using?

Comment: @Jackdaw version 17.2.20172.2188. There aren't any other controls in the xaml so there shouldn't be any issue with that

Comment: Show your full markup - how you set the `DataContext`? I'm using `v18.2` and it's working as expected.

Comment: @Jackdaw seems like the issue was a custom control we were using, for whatever reason it was overriding the navigation behaviour

Comment: This is why I was asking for the full `xaml` code.  But you wrote _There aren't any other controls in the xaml..._ In most cases the short snippet like you provided isn't enough to help...